# k8s ingress with Nginx, what is the overall flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I'm trying to wrap my head around the flow of traffic for a k8s cluster which is deployed on AWS as a k8s cluster and has a Nginx load balancer through K8s ingress.  Specifically what I'm trying to understand is, what role the external load balancer (in this case aws) plays, and how it in turn routes traffic to the K8s cluster ingress.  I tried searching for a few demos or some documentation on how its setup, but all I found is setup steps.  I'm trying to get the high level overview of how the traffic flows.

Answer (score 2):

Traffic flows if you are using the ingress

```
Internet > ingress > Kubernetes service > Workload PODs
```

Ingress controller will be managing SSL/TLS certs & configuration and refreshing the changes as per requirement.

in more details

```
 Internet > LB > ingress > K8s Cluster > Kubernetes service > Workload PODs
```

you can check this out : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: thanks for this, this is what I was looking for 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNZ9qOoJ0II